# Overlay text using css after

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add an overlay text on a div if it does not have required amount of characters.

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jason99/LYxmF/

First three characters should be in the blue and rest in the red color.

CSS code

```
.overlay-text {
    color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
}
.overlay-text:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: '******';
    color: red;
}
```

HTML

```
<span class="overlay-text">***</span>
```

Comment: remove position absolute and left from :after

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/LYxmF/5/) You can use this

Comment: @jason: Just saw your comment in the answer. Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LYxmF/7/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by adding a negative z-index to the pseudo element and also positioning it absolutely in relation to the main span.

```
.overlay-text {
    color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative; /* Added this */

}
.overlay-text:after {
    content: '******';
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; /* Added this */
}
```

**Notes:**

1. If the characters in the span are different from * then they would kind of show the *s behind it, so you would have to add a solid background to the `.overlay-text` (say white).
2. Adding a negative z-index to the pseudo element would make it unselectable but I guess that should be fine given your requirement statement.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LYxmF/7/)

Comment: Good Solution with explanations :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `position:absolute; left:0;` from `.overlay-text:after`. If you need you can use it in `.overlay-text` like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LYxmF/4/)**

CSS:

```
.overlay-text {
    color: blue;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.overlay-text:after {
    content:'******';
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: No , He meant something different. He wants first three characters should come top thats why he set z-index. But color collapses

Comment: `first three characters should come top` i dont get what you are trying to say? Did you mean it must overlap with red txt?

Comment: @Kiran count the characters in your fiddle

Comment: @Jason Take a look at my fiddle that i commented

Comment: @user3168736 it should show all blue in your example

Comment: @user3168736: I think jason's need is that he needs total 6 characters. If span has 3 chars they should be blue and the other 3 in red. If span has 4 they should be in blue and other 2 in red.

Comment: Yes @harry i understand it after he commented here and tried and posted a solution.

Comment: @Harry worked perfect. Thanks! If you can post as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/LYxmF/8/)

```
 .overlay-text:before {
  content: '###';
  color: blue;
  position:relative;
  }
.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '******';
  color: red;
}
```

At last i understand your question and just add position. It ll solve your problem.

**EDIT** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/LYxmF/10/)

It invloves z-index and positioning. Give negative z-index .